# image picker memory crash after dismiss

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

i m facing a problem from last 4 days i.e i have to simply open camera on a view controller having map on it and have to save the clicked image(of original size) in gallery when doing so  my app start receiving memory warnings and just crash after some time ..

What i think problem is that every time imagepicker is dismissed my map is start rendering .

Also crash is on specific ios and device i.e ios 8.1.3 + iphone 4s.

any suggestions are appreciated.

Please help.

Comment: You getting any error or warning before crash ? Kindly add it here.

Comment: recieved memory warnings for 5 to 10 time  and after that app crashed due low memory pressure.

Comment: Could you post code please? And does app works fine if you comment code which uses image picker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a hetic weekend i found the solution although its an patch but works for me .So what i have done i simply block the main thread untill the imagepicker controller is dismissed .

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
__weak typeof(picker) wSelf = picker;
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [wSelf dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        @try {


            [self saveImage:info];
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"Exception:%@",exception);
        }
        @finally {
        }

    }];});}

-(void)saveImage:(NSDictionary *)info{
[KAppdelegate ShowLoader];

UIImage *image=(UIImage *)[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];



ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myApp.saveToCameraRoll", NULL);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
   [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[image CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[image imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){

        if (error) {
            // handle the error
        }
        else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // perhaps indicate to the user that save has finished

            });
        }

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);

    }];

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

});}
```